# How to tar all newly generated files in a directory every two hour and moving that tared files to another directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

files will generate every 5th minute in /kit directory.Want to tar all the files and move that files to `/kit/bkp` directory every 2 hr

Comment: You dialed the wrong number; this is not the scripting service. But we are glad to help if you edit the question to show your attempt for that script. We can point out what went wrong and suggest what to change. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
find your_path -t f -mmin 5 -exec tar -zcvf your_compress_file.tar.gz {} +
```

You can make an script and put your script into `crontab`.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script and set it to run with cron jobs or systemd timers. Include the appropriate `tar` command in the script and use the exclude flag for tar to avoid taring the `/tar/bkp` folder. And use `find` with the `-mmin 120` flag to limit the files tarred to files modified in the last 120 minutes.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
source='/kit'
dest='/kit/bkp'
find "${source}" -mmin 120 -exec \
  tar cpf "${dest}/$(date +'%Y%m%d%H').tar" --exclude="${dest}" {} +
```

This script will be executed with `/bin/bash`, defines a source and destination path, selects only files that have been modified in the last 120 minutes, and then creates a tar file named for the year-month-day-hour in the destination folder, preserving permissions and ownership, and excluding the destination folder.

Then type `crontab -e` as a user with read and execute access to `/kit`... write, read, and execute access to `/kit/bkp`... and read and execute permission to the script we made before. In the cron file add a line like this:

```
0 */2 * * * /path/to/your/script.sh > /dev/null
```

This will run the script every 2 hours on the hour and pipe stdout to `/dev/null` to keep the script silent unless it produces an error. Cron should message you if an error occurs.

Comment: every 5 minutes a file with .log extension is generating, have to tar only all those files with that extension to backup directory.

Comment: Ah, I see, then Using the find command with the option `-mmin 120` to limit the files tar runs on to files modified in the last 120 minutes is your best bet. Everything is the same, except the line with tar in the script needs to be modified to include the find command.

Comment: Now i faced a problem that the source directory contains many files in which the files with name such as starting with 'log' and ending with .log should only tared.

Comment: what to do for that

Comment: You could start by searching google for the `find` command. Or type `man find` in the linux console. Look, I've already done 95% of the work for you. Stack Exchange isn't really meant to solicit other people to write code for you. That's why your question is getting down-voted. It's meant as a way to exchange knowledge. I've told you want needs to be done. I've given you everything you need to know what to do next. It's up to you now.